# No subscriptions were found for 'None' after az login why is this?

Tags: azure-cli

I have a project where I have admin rights and several pipelines in this project, I want to learn what can I do with azure cli and learn to work with it, so far I've installed it and used the
'az login' command, and the login was successful but when I use 'az group list' it says I have no suscriptions something like that, someone knows what am I missing? im completely new to azure cli sorry if the question seems dumb

is it possible to:
execute a pipeline from the cli?
schedule a pipeline?
and pretty much manage pipelines?
that's what I want to achieve with azure cli

Thank you for all your help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> when I use 'az group list' it says I have no subscriptions something like that, someone knows what am I missing?

The command [`az group list`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/group?view=azure-cli-latest#az-group-list) list resource groups in the azure subscription, the error means your login account does not have a role in the subscription, you need to add it to the subscription as a role first, e.g. `Contributor`, just navigate to the subscription in the portal -> `Access control (IAM)` -> Add, follow this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/quickstart-assign-role-user-portal).

If you can make sure your user account is already in a subscription, after login, use [`az account set --subscription <subscription-id>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/account?view=azure-cli-latest#az-account-set) to set the subscription.

> is it possible to: execute a pipeline from the cli? schedule a pipeline? and pretty much manage pipelines? that's what I want to achieve with azure cli

Yes, you can. To use Azure DevOps CLI, you need to add devops extension first, for more details about the install and configuration,  refer to [Get started with Azure DevOps CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/cli/?view=azure-devops).

```
 az extension add --name azure-devops
```

After that, use the commands here - [`az pipelines`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/ext/azure-devops/pipelines?view=azure-cli-latest), e.g. use `az pipelines run` to execute a pipeline , use `az pipelines update` to update the YAML file path to configure schedules for pipelines.

Comment: Thank you very much!